# Getting Google Glass gestures in a Unity app?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-gdk

I have successfully built a Unity app for glass using the export to Andrdoid Project build setting, but I can't for the life of me get input from the touchpad.  I've tried using a OnGenericMotionEvent or OnGesture or all sorts of callback overrides in the UnityNativeActivity, but they are never called.  My guess is that there is a different activity that is overriding the input and preventing it from getting to the activity that you can override.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The touchpad on Glass is a D-pad. That should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I had overlooked the AndroidInput.secondaryTouchpad functionality.  It turns out that Unity already supports it!

Answer (score 0):

Use a [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html). I have successfully detected TAPs and SWIPEs on Glass using this, but I haven't tried it on an UnityNativeActivity. In theory it should work.